# Crystal Reports, Drill-Down/Sub Report Based on SQL SP Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, drilldown

I have a main report which displays products within their relevant groups, lets say 'Red' and 'Blue' for example.

It looks something like this;

```
Customer1       

                Qty      Price

Red Products     24       75
Blue Products    75       16
```

This report is based on a a database table.

I then have a sub report (Stored Procedure) which will display all of the related products under a grouping (e.g. Red or Blue) and asks for this parameter.

The issue I'm having is linking the grouping name from the main report, as a parameter for the sub report.

**Note: The main report is a Cross-Tab**

I've tried inserting the sub-report and then 'Change sub report links' but this hasn't worked for me.

The end goal is that the user can double click on the grouping to be presented with a list of all products within that grouping. Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a sub report run from within a cross-tab, you may have to move the report to a standard group/summary report (or have a single row cross tab on the group footer showing the values for that group).